# Does the Question have a code against killing?

Tags: dc, comics

I am a new fan to the Question and I have a query. Does the Question have a code (like Batman) against killing, or does he believe it's OK as long as it's justified (like Rorschach)?

[image: Question throwing a card]

Comment: "*However, Vic quickly gets drawn into a drug war which ultimately forces him to kill in order to save Jackie's life. This marks a major turning point in the Question's career as he thinks to himself that he didn't feel anything and would kill again if needed. Though it is not entirely clear what the Question's current view is on murder, he kills again in the 1991 Brave and the Bold mini-series and the 2005 Question mini-series.* - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_(comics)

Comment: He's certainly killed before but wikipedia is unsure as to whether he feels bad about it or simply that it's justified by circumstances.

Comment: @Valorum your comments are well thought out and backed with citations, you should post an answer to this question.

Comment: @KMo - To be honest, I'm not especially interested in simply dumping a wikipedia link/quote onto the site when I've not read the actual issues.